# Does blockchain.info backup wallet include also the next addresses

Tags: wallet, blockchain.info

The standard client's wallet includes a key pool of 100 extra pre-generated addresses, which are the next ones to be "generated" when you ask an extra address.

Does the blockchain.info's backup wallet do such a thing, too?

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10557/153

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't. At least not from what can be seen in the "Export Unencrypted" option and I doubt that it would be any different using the encrypted option.

Comment: Lol I noticed and added the same answer right now

Comment: Ah, I beat you by 20 seconds or so. :)