# Does a blockchain.info My Wallet have a key pool?

Tags: wallet, private-key, blockchain.info

Does a wallet in blockchain.info My Wallet contain a pool of extra keys as in bitcoin-qt?

Should the wallet be backed up after every new address is created, or only after several are created?

Comment: (partial duplicate, I'm unsure if it should be closed or not)

Comment: A duplicate all right. Now why didn't I find it in search? Edited a bit the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It doesn't](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4627/does-blockchain-info-backup-wallet-include-also-the-next-addresses) (or, at least, didn't).

Email backups will be sent to you every time you create a new address.